# How to make spin the wheel game in ionic with probability

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, html5-canvas, ionic4

I am developing a game in ionic 4 'spin the wheel'. so far I am able to spin the wheel which stops randomly on any of the sections. Can anyone help me with setting probability to sections so that users will have fewer chances to win? I would like to pre-define each section with some percentage value. for eg section with 0 will have 50% 4 will have 10% etc, and the greatest value will have a 1% chance to win. below code, I have tried.

SpinWheel.ts

```
export class SpinWheel {

  @ViewChild('myCanvas', { static: false }) myCanvas: ElementRef;


  colors = ["#2a8251", "#dc0927", "#414243", "#dc0927", "#2E2C75",
    "#dc0927", "#414243", "#dc0927", "#2E2C75",
    "#dc0927"];
  restaraunts = ["0", "32", "15", "19",
    "4", "21", "2", "25",
    "17", "34"];

  startAngle = 0;
  arc = 2 * Math.PI / 10;
  spinTimeout = null;

  spinArcStart = 10;
  spinTime = 0;
  spinTimeTotal = 0;

  ctx;

  spinAngleStart;

  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.draw();
  }



  draw() {
    this.drawRouletteWheel();
  }

  drawRouletteWheel() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("wheelcanvas");

    var outsideRadius = 140;
    var textRadius = 120;
    var insideRadius = 25;

    this.ctx = (<HTMLCanvasElement>this.myCanvas.nativeElement).getContext('2d');
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);


    this.ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    this.ctx.lineWidth = 2;

    this.ctx.font = 'bold 12px sans-serif';

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      var angle = this.startAngle + i * this.arc;
      this.ctx.fillStyle = this.colors[i];

      this.ctx.beginPath();
      this.ctx.arc(150, 150, outsideRadius, angle, angle + this.arc, false);
      this.ctx.arc(150, 150, insideRadius, angle + this.arc, angle, true);
      this.ctx.stroke();
      this.ctx.fill();

      this.ctx.save();
      this.ctx.shadowOffsetX = -1;
      this.ctx.shadowOffsetY = -1;
      this.ctx.shadowBlur = 0;
      //this.ctx.shadowColor   = "rgb(220,220,220)";
      this.ctx.fillStyle = "white";
      this.ctx.translate(150 + Math.cos(angle + this.arc / 2) * textRadius, 150 + Math.sin(angle + this.arc / 2) * textRadius);
      this.ctx.rotate(angle + this.arc / 2 + Math.PI / 2);
      var text = this.restaraunts[i];
      this.ctx.fillText(text, -this.ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 0);
      this.ctx.restore();
    }

    //Arrow
    this.ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.moveTo(150 - 4, 150 - (outsideRadius + 5));
    this.ctx.lineTo(150 + 4, 150 - (outsideRadius + 5));
    this.ctx.lineTo(150 + 4, 150 - (outsideRadius - 5));
    this.ctx.lineTo(150 + 9, 150 - (outsideRadius - 5));
    this.ctx.lineTo(150 + 0, 150 - (outsideRadius - 13));
    this.ctx.lineTo(150 - 9, 150 - (outsideRadius - 5));
    this.ctx.lineTo(150 - 4, 150 - (outsideRadius - 5));
    this.ctx.lineTo(150 - 4, 150 - (outsideRadius + 5));
    this.ctx.fill();
  }

  spin() {
    this.spinAngleStart = Math.random() * 10 + 10;
    this.spinTime = 0;
    this.spinTimeTotal = Math.random() * 3 + 4 * 1000;
    this.rotateWheel();
  }

  rotateWheel() {
    this.spinTime += 30;
    if (this.spinTime >= this.spinTimeTotal) {
      this.stopRotateWheel();
      return;
    }
    var spinAngle = this.spinAngleStart - this.easeOut(this.spinTime, 0, this.spinAngleStart, this.spinTimeTotal);
    this.startAngle += (spinAngle * Math.PI / 180);
    this.drawRouletteWheel();
    this.spinTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      this.rotateWheel();
    }, 30);
  }

  stopRotateWheel() {
    clearTimeout(this.spinTimeout);
    var degrees = this.startAngle * 180 / Math.PI + 90;
    var arcd = this.arc * 180 / Math.PI;
    var index = Math.floor((360 - degrees % 360) / arcd);
    this.ctx.save();
    this.ctx.font = 'bold 30px sans-serif';
    var text = this.restaraunts[index]
    //this.ctx.fillText(text, 150 - this.ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 150 + 10);
    alert("You got:\n" + text);
    this.ctx.restore();
  }

  // t: current time
  // b: start value
  // c: change in value
  // d: duration

  easeOut(t, b, c, d) {
    return c * Math.sin(t/d * (Math.PI/2)) + b;
}

}
```

spin_wheel.html

```
<div class="wheel">
  <canvas #myCanvas width="auto" height="300"></canvas>
  <div class="icon-center"><img class="app-logo" (click)="spin()" src="../../assets/icon/favicon.png"/></div>     
</div>
```

See attached image [spin wheel screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZ2yD.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For wheel spins odds count  slots on the wheel. The image has 10 slots with odds 1/10  (10%) for any. For 1/2 odds add prize to 5 of the slots. (5/10 = 1/2 odds). For 1/100 odds (1%) you need 100 slots.Note that  in many places it is illegal to miss represent the odds. If just for personal fun, create an array 100 items long, in that array add the slot numbers, If slot 0 is 1/100 add it to the array once, if 2 is 1/50 add it twice twice, and so on. Then to pick a random slot with your weighted odds just randomly select and item from the array  slots[Math.random() * 100 | 0]

Comment: @Blindman67 i have added those numbers in slot for temporary purpose. All slots will have some images or text in it. Can you please explain me with any example